# Compilation and Macros

Tags: compilation, macros, common-lisp

This is a quotation on the topic "compilation and macro expansion", from the book [Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to symbolic computation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1537391.Common_LISP).

```
(defmacro bad-announce-macro ()
(format t "~%Hi mom!"))
(defun say-hi ()
(bad-announce-macro))
> (compile 'say-hi)
Hi, mom!
SAY-HI
> (say-hi)
NIL
```

In the above example the macro was expanded as part of the process of
compiling `SAY-HI`. So the compiler said `‘‘Hi, mom!’’` The result of the
macro was `NIL`, so that’s what got compiled into the body of `SAY-HI`. When
we call the compiled `SAY-HI` function, it says nothing because the macro has
been replaced with its expansion.

---

In this quotation, the author says that

> the macro has been replaced with its expansion

Okay, so shouldn't it atleast show the printed `"Hi mom!"` ?  Because though the macro doesn't return anything, but it still replaced by something (it's expansion). Based on the code, I hypothesized that
 when a function is called after it is compiled, all the macros, that are called in it's body, are expanded into the **result they return** , not into whatever they have in their own bodies.

I'm not sure if this is right. And the reason for doing this is also not clear.

Comment: The expansion of a macro is the return value of the macro. Since the macro returns `NIL`, its expansion is `NIL`, and that's what it is replaced with in the `SAY-HI` function.

Comment: @jkiiski : But why does the function print `"Hi mom!"` until it is not compiled?

Comment: The macro is expanded when the code is compiled (the side effects of the macro happen during the expansion). Until then it's interpreted code (and the macro is expanded on the fly when the function is called) in whatever implementation you're using.

Comment: So, I'll see the side effects of a macro, whenever it is expanded. And it is expanded only once in the case of compilation, and every call after that will use the result of the macro. Whereas in the case of interpreted code, it is expanded every time it is called. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How often a macro is expanded is unspecified.

Interpreted Lisp in LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 49 > (say-hi)

Hi mom!
Hi mom!
NIL
```

The macro expansion is done twice at runtime here.

In compiled code we expect that no macro expansion is necessary at runtime. Thus in your example nothing will be printed, since your generated code does nothing:

```
CL-USER 50 > (compile 'say-hi)

Hi mom!
SAY-HI
NIL
NIL

CL-USER 51 > (say-hi)
NIL
```

The macro expansion is `NIL`.

```
CL-USER 52 > (macroexpand '(bad-announce-macro))

Hi mom!
NIL        ; <- the macro expansion
T
```